# Does the word HA always refer to a weak acid?

Tags: acid-base

I was wondering if HA always represents a weak acid or can it also represent strong acids.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: There is absolutely no info about how the strong the acid is in this notation. HA may refer to both weak and strong acids. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_strength

Comment: In fact, it need not to refer to an acid at all. E.g, in a biochemistry context, A may mean a particular coenzyme or a substrate, and HA may mean it's hydrogenated form. Considering A as the rest of a (weak) Acidic molecule is implied from the given context or it is given explicitly.